# Does the following inequality hold? $\sum\limits_{i=1}^a\sum\limits_{j=1}^b\sum\limits_{k=1}^c|A_iB_jC_k|\leq 1$ as $||A||=||B||=||C||=1$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Given three vectors $A\in \mathbb{R}^a$, $B\in \mathbb{R}^b$ and $C\in \mathbb{R}^c$, with $||A||=||B||=||C||=1$, where $||\cdot||$ denotes the $l_2$ norm. Then does the following inequality necessarily hold?
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^a\sum\limits_{j=1}^b\sum\limits_{k=1}^c|A_iB_jC_k|\leq1.$$
Or is there any famous inequality that can imply the above one?

Comment: Note that you can write your sum as $$\Biggl(\sum_{i = 1}^a \lvert A_i\rvert\Biggr)\cdot \Biggl(\sum_{j = 1}^b \lvert B_j\rvert\Biggr)\cdot \Biggl(\sum_{k = 1}^c \lvert C_k\rvert\Biggr).$$ That should make finding counterexamples easier.

Comment: @Arthur Inequalities similar to Cauchy-Schwarz would involve $$\sum_iA_iB_iC_i$$ not $$\sum_{i,j,k}A_iB_jC_k.$$ More structurally, the question is in the realm of $L^1$ spaces while Cauchy-Schwarz deals with $L^2$ spaces.

Comment: Yes, for $\sum\limits_i A_iB_iC_i$, the inequality seems to be true. Meanwhile, for the above one, one simply counterexample is to set $A_i=\frac{1}{a}$, $B_i=\frac{1}{b}$ and $C_i=\frac{1}{c}$.